# JavaScript - Printing two numbers (Not a string) in a single line. Not do the conversion

Tags: javascript

if I have these variables:

```
var a = 5
var b = 10
```

How can I return it in single line with console.log ?
Like this:

```
5 10
```

**IMPORTANT:** But the types must remain as Numbers **NOT** a String. It is mandatory to have white-spaces between the numbers.

How can I solve it?

Comment: But `console.log` *will* coerce primitives' input into a string..? It won't change the type of the passed variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you insist:

```
console.log(a, b);
```

Will print your desired output:

> 5 10

(no *explicit* string conversion involved)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by 'the types must remain numbers' if you are printing to the console...I would just do:

`console.log(a + ' ' + b)`